# Count common, mutually exclusive elements in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df <- structure(c("IGTB10", "IGTB10", "IGTB100", "IGTB1004", "IGTB1007", 
            "IGTB1009", "CD4 T-cells", "Monocytes", "CD4 T-cells", "CD4 T-cells", 
            "CD4 T-cells", "Monocytes"), .Dim = c(6L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
              NULL, c("Individual", "cellType")))
```

I would like to count how many individuals have both Monocytes and CD4 cell types, how many have only monocytes and CD4 cells each. What would be the easiest way to group or aggregate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very fast answer without any packages, do table to get whether each individual has CD4 or monocytes

```
table(df[,1],df[,2])

           CD4 T-cells Monocytes
  IGTB10             1         1
  IGTB100            1         0
  IGTB1004           1         0
  IGTB1007           1         0
  IGTB1009           0         1
```

If you take the sum of rows,

```
rowSums(table(df[,1],df[,2]))
  IGTB10  IGTB100 IGTB1004 IGTB1007 IGTB1009 
       2        1        1        1        1
```

Only IGTB10 has 2, meaning both CD4 and monocyte

If we use all the code in a stretch,

```
sum(rowSums(table(df[,1],df[,2]))==2)
```

Only one individual has both CD4 and monocytes